# Difference between = and Ctrl + =

Tags: entity, free-form-input

What is a difference between  <kbd>$\textbf{=}$</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>$\textbf{=}$</kbd>?

For instance

there are some examples, but result is same.

[image: Flags]

and

[image: Textual Output]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<kbd>=</kbd> can only be entered at the beginning of a cell and then interprets the entire cell content as a free-form WolframAlpha query.  By contrast, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> can be used to create an inline WolframAlpha interpretation cell that appears in the middle of an otherwise normal expression.

For example, we can start by typing `ImageDimensions[` followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> to create an inline cell:

[image: ctrl-= preparation screenshot]

We then enter our query text...

[image: ctrl-= query screenshot]

... and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

[image: ctrl-= after pressing enter]

Finally, we can type `]` to close the expression and then evaluate it:

[image: ctrl-=: final result]

If we click the checkbox within the inline cell then that cell will be replaced with the equivalent *Mathematica* expression.

Comment: In addition after entering `Ctrl-+` and a request like **plot sin x** you can click the checkbox and your original input gets transformed into the Mathematica equivalent input statement.

Comment: @JackLaVigne I added a note to that effect... thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To add to WReach's answer, since <kbd>=</kbd> works on the entire cell, it can return formatted Wolfram|Alpha pods when there is no corresponding Wolfram Language syntax. It wouldn't make much sense to have a formatted W|A pod inline.

Compare <kbd>=</kbd>

[image]

vs <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd>

[image]

Clicking on the gray question mark says exactly this:

[image]